# Mozilla support for break-before: avoid-column

Tags: css, cross-browser, mozilla, page-break-before

Mozilla Firefox v113.0 documentation says it supports column views and the `break-before` CSS property completely. But when I set `break-before: avoid-column` OR `break-before: column` it does not identify the property.
The need is to set fixed position of multiple div elements once the page has loaded. My solution is working on every browser but Mozilla.

I use JS to set class `.first-item` and `.last-item` to the div to fix their position.

PS. All div elements are dynamically generated.
PPS. I do not want to use `break-inside`

```
.main {
    column-count: 2;
    column-width: 36rem;
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;

    .item-wapper {
         break-inside: avoid-column;

         &.first-item {
             break-before: column;
         }

         &.last-item {
             &:not(.first-item) {
                 break-before: avoid-column;
             }
         }
    }
}
```

I also tried using
`page-break-before` but to no avail.